# Making a fraction from two arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, fractions

Right now I am working on a project that will add fractions. I have two arrays, one for the numerator and one for the denominator. How would I use those two arrays to form a fraction? I have tried making a new method and dividing the two arrays and that did not work. Any help is appreciated, thanks! This is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction {
private int numerator;
private int denominator;
private double ratio_value;

private void setNumerator()
{
    numerator = 1;
}

private void setDenominator()
{
    denominator = 1;
}

private void setRatio_Value()
{
    ratio_value = 1.0;
}

public void getNumerator()
{
Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
int numer [] = new int [7];

for (int i = 0; i<numer.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the numerator of 7 fractions: ");
    numer[i] = k.nextInt();
}

}

public void getDenominator()
{
    Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
    int denom [] = new int [7];

    for (int i = 0; i<denom.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the denominmator of 7 fractions: ");
        denom[i] = k.nextInt();
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I am understanding correctly, you would like to read in a bunch of numerators and then a bunch of denominators and form a new array holding all of the fractions? If so I would like to point out a few things that might help you accomplish your goal. I have made comments in the code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Fraction {
private int numerator;
private int num_array[7];
private int denom_array[7];
private int denominator;
private double ratio_values[7];

private void setNumerator()
{
    numerator = 1;
}

private void setDenominator()
{
    denominator = 1;
}

private void setRatio_Value()
{
    ratio_value = 1.0;
}

public void getNumerator()
{
Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
//this array below is a *local* array, after your function ends it will be completely gone... you should save it up above as I recommended
//read the numerators into the above array directly
int numer [] = new int [7];

for (int i = 0; i<numer.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println("Enter the numerator of 7 fractions: ");
    num_array[i] = k.nextInt();
}

}

public void getDenominator()
{
    Scanner k = new Scanner (System.in);
    int denom [] = new int [7];
    //do something similar for this
    for (int i = 0; i<denom.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the denominmator of 7 fractions: ");
        denom_array[i] = k.nextInt();
    }
}
//new function to calculate new fractions
public void setFractions() {
    for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
        ratio_values[i] = (double) num_array[i] / (double) denom_array[i];
    }
}
```

You will not be able to divide the two arrays directly, so the above function performs the same operation, but element-by-element.

Comment: For some reason when you set the fraction I am getting a NullPointerException. When inputting the numerators and denominators I inputted all 1's so division by zero is not a problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you want this fraction to be stored? In a third array?

You should make a constructor by the way

You could do something like this:

```
public static Fraction[] makeFractions(int[] numerators, int[] denominators){
   Fraction[] fractions;
   //This is assuming that the numerators and denominators arrays have the same length
   for(int i = 0; i < numerators.length(); i++){
       fractions[i] = new Fraction(numerators[i], denominators[i]);
   }
   return fractions;
}
```

Sorry if there are any typos.